# Retrieving Map Composer Items using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, print-composer, qgis-2.18

In a **QgsComposition** i would like to retrieve the list of all Composer Items.

I don't want to specify item type.

The function should have been `composerItems()` but the help says it isn't available in Python Bindings (I'm using QGIS 2.18).

Is there a way to access that list ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just call "items()":

```
the_items = my_composer.items()
```

Comment: That answer should be the accepted answer. It is correct and the shortest.

Comment: Thanks Nyall ... i'm so sad i'm not able to find it by myself in the online class reference documentation ...

Comment: That's because it comes from the underlying QGraphicsScene base class - there's a link on the doc page to see the base class members

Answer (score 3):

You can use following structure: (as an example)

```
composition = iface.activeComposers()[0].composition()
items_model = composition.itemsModel()
list_of_composer_items = items_model.zOrderList()

# OUT:
# [<qgis._core.QgsComposerArrow object at ..>, <qgis._core.QgsComposerLegend 
# object at ..>, <qgis._core.QgsComposerScaleBar object at ..>, 
# <qgis._core.QgsComposerMap object at ..>]
```

> NOTE: "This list includes both items currently in the composition and items which have been removed from the composition."

**UPDATE**: Thanks to @ndawson. `composition.items()` returns existing items in a composition in addition to three more objects; two `QGraphicsRectItem` and a `QgsPaperItem` (QGIS 2.18). Even if you don't add any item, those three items will exist in the list.

```
>>> composition = iface.activeComposers()[0].composition()
>>> composition.items()    
[<PyQt4.QtGui.QGraphicsRectItem object at ..>,
 <PyQt4.QtGui.QGraphicsRectItem object at ..>,
 <qgis._core.QgsPaperItem object at ..>]
```

Comment: Thanks Kadir ... i didn't have a look at this `QgsComposerModel` so far ...

Comment: If you reopen QGIS, you just get existing items.  In addition to existing items, using `zOrderList()` gives you items removed  **in related session**.

Comment: Is `isRemoved` the function to use to discriminate those removed and the other ? Haven't tested it yet ...